# Image Analysis - using calculated distances in x y coordinate system to identify surrounding cells - R

Tags: r, dataframe, identity, cells, complex-data-types

I have what I think is a tough problem, so I look forward to hearing some options - here is my favorite working example :

```
 cellID         X          Y Area   AvgGFP DeviationGFP   AvgRFP DeviationsRFP Slice GUI.ID
1       1  18.20775  26.309859  568 5.389085     7.803248 12.13028      5.569880     0      1
2       2  39.78755   9.505495  546 5.260073     6.638375 17.44505     17.220153     0      1
3       3  30.50000  28.250000    4 6.000000     4.000000  8.50000      1.914854     0      1
4       4  38.20233 132.338521  257 3.206226     5.124264 14.04669      4.318130     0      1
5       5  43.22467  35.092511  454 6.744493     9.028574 11.49119      5.186897     0      1
6       6  57.06534 130.355114  352 3.781250     5.713022 20.96591     14.303546     0      1
7       7  86.81765  15.123529 1020 6.043137     8.022179 16.36471     19.194279     0      1
8       8  75.81932 132.146417  321 3.666667     5.852172 99.47040     55.234726     0      1
9       9 110.54277  36.339233  678 4.159292     6.689660 12.65782      4.264624     0      1
10     10 127.83480  11.384886  569 4.637961     6.992881 11.39192      4.287963     0      1
```

This is a text file with information regarding an image, I have many others with more rows. Columns X - Y correspond to the X Y pixel coordinates on the image. By entering this command - I get a nice representation of the data in a plot :

```
p <- ggplot(total_stats[[slice]], aes(X, Y))
p + geom_point(aes(colour = AvgGFP)) + scale_colour_gradient(low = 'white', high = 'black')
```

What I want to do is the following. 
1) ID cells with a threshold above above a certain AvgGFP value, lets say 75. I want to take the identified cells and take their AvgGFP values and put them in a data.frame called hiAvgGFP.
2) ID any cells that are within a certain distance from the hi AvgGFP cells, making sure to exclude the hi AvgGFP used as the center. Let's set the radius to 50. I want to take the identified cells and take their AvgGFP values and put them in a data.frame called surrounding_cells.
3) Next I want to perform this process on all data.frames - there are 40 called slice1-slice40, which are all contained in 'total_stats'

I am imagining the end result to look like this -

2 new data.frames (hiAvgGFP) and surrounding cell (surrounding_cells)
each of these data.frames will have 40 columns containing AvgGFP values from slices 1-40. Since all slices do not have an equal number of rows - fill empty cells in data set with NA

MAN! that was tough typing out! As always any and all help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have some notion of what a cell is but I'll be darned if I can figure out what it might be.

Comment: @DWin sorry for not being clear. You will notice there is a cellID column - basically each row corresponds to a cell

Comment: There are no such cells with an AvgGFP above your criterion. Can you specify the desired outcome from the data you have offered.

Comment: @Dwin - I was using a value from the entire data set. Let's set the threshold for 6.5 AvgGFP. There is only one cell in this set that meets that criteria. So the hiAvgGFP data.set for this slice should look like ' AvgGFP
1 6.744493'
Then the surrounding_cells should look like this if the radius is set to 50
 AvgGFP
1 5.389085
2 5.260073
3 6
4 6.043137

Answer (score 1):

You are quite vague on some critical details regarding your data. If your data is gridded then I would recommend coercing this data into a raster class object and then using a focal function to calculate your conditional cell calculation.

If this data is in fact, not gridded then you could use the functionality of the spdep package to calculate K nearest neighbors using knearneigh or dnearneigh. You can easily coerce your current data into an sp spatialPointsDataFrame object to conduct this type of analysis.

Another alternative is that if you have access to the original rasters then you can apply a focal function to the raster extract function, using the above point locations, to accomplish your goal.

If you have a spatial problem then it is prudent to leverage the spatial classes in R.